# how to clean ginger residue from my plastic juicer containers?

Tags: cleaning, juice

I was juicing unpeeled ginger over the weekend, and even though I washed both the main juicing chamber/Auger housing and the juice container after using them, they seem stained, with slightly sticky residue in hard-to-get places and they're tinted slightly yellow.

The brush the juicer came with has helped a bit, but not fully. I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofDAV-zoFl0), but it's not super clear how food-safe its recommendations (OxiClean, Sun Oxygen Cleaner) are.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Check the instruction for the juicer for what is safe.   I would hesitate to use harsh chemicals or abrasives on a plastic component.  Ginger is slightly acidic.

Answer (score 1):

i would hesitate before using chemical methods like the video you linked suggests, but you may have some success with scrubbing with an SOS pad or chore boy, or even some high grit sand paper (something like 240 grit)

Answer (score 1):

Since the plastic surfaces will continue to be exposed to food, you might try a food-safe solution, such as lemon juice, white vinegar or baking soda. Vinegar and baking soda can be combined into a paste for a scrub. Ammonia might work, but you'd have to thoroughly flush afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If the Sun cleaner they used is the same as Oxiclean, then it's a mix of sodium carbonate and hydrogen peroxide plus minor additives.  Since it's not made with food safety in mind, the additives or even the carbonate could have things you don't want in your food.

The yellow in ginger comes from [gingerol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gingerol) which should dissolve in grain alcohol.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how or why backing soda and vinegar would work.  Maybe they are both different enough on the pH spectrum that they could work.  You don't want to eat ammonia,  but it's also very water soluble. If you can't smell it anymore its not enough to be a problem ever. Try an acid like lemon or vinegar, then try baking soda, a base (pH > neutral (7)).